# Plotting stacked histograms in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some data effectively so I can visualise it but I am having some trouble. I have two values. One is discrete (0 or 1) and called `label`. The other is a continuous value anywhere between 0 and 1. I wish to create a histogram, where on the X axis there would be numerous bars, for example one for every .25 of data, so four bars, where the first has the value of 0-0.25, the second 0.25-0.5, third 0.5-0.75 and fourth 0.75-1.

The y axis will then be split up by whether label is a 1 or a 0, so we end up with a graph like this :

[image: Please excuse the poor paint image!]

If there is any effective, intelligent ways to split up my data (rather than just having four bars hardcoded for these values) I would be interested in this too, though that probably warrants another question. I will post it when I have code from this running.

I have both values stored in numpy arrays as follows, but am unsure how to plot a graphs like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as P

variable_values = trainData.get_vector('variable') #returns one dimensional numpy array of vals
label_values = trainData.get_vector('label')
x = alchemy_category_score_values[alchemy_category_score_values != '?'].astype(float) #removing void vals
y = label_values[alchemy_category_score_values != '?'].astype(float)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.title("Feature breakdown histogram")
plt.xlabel("Variable")
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylabel("Label")
plt.ylim(0, 1)
xvals = np.linspace(0,1,.02)

plt.show()
```

The matplotlib tutorial shows the following code to roughly achieve what I want, but I can't really understand how it works ([LINK](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html)) :

```
P.figure()

n, bins, patches = P.hist(x, 10, normed=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)

P.show()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit :

I am now getting the error :

```
AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 5 or scalar
```

I have printed my two numpy arrays and they are of equal length, one is discrete, the other continuous. Here is the code I am running :

```
x = variable_values[variable_values != '?'].astype(float)
y = label_values[label_values != '?'].astype(float)

print x #printing numpy arrays of equal size, x is continuous, y is discrete. Both of type float now.
print y

N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.45       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, y,   width, color='r') #error occurs here
p2 = plt.bar(ind, x, width, color='y',
             bottom=x)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,81,10))
plt.legend( (p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your x values must be a 2d array. Did you notice the command `x = mu + sigma*P.randn(1000,3)` in the link you gave? This is used to make the three stacked bars.

Comment: The error comes from the `N` variable, which is the number of bars in the histogram. Either write a 4, or use `len(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this other tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) from the same Matplotlib gallery will be much more revealing to you ...

Notice that the second series of data has an extra argument in the call: `bottom`

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans,   width, color='r', yerr=womenStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, color='y',
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=menStd)
```

Just replace `menMeans` with `x` and `womenMeans` with `y`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would I put for yerr in this case, I dont quite understand how that works :)

Comment: `yerr` can be omitted. It allows you to put an error range on top of each of the histogram bars. It is optional.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I have updated my question above. I think I am close now but cannot figure out this error message, can you see anything I have done incorrectly here?

Comment: See my comment on the question: fix the value of `N`